# How to retrieve attributes of an option item in HTML select list?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to get two values. For one, it is working but for another one it is not. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="product-price">
    <div class="lefts-column">
        <span>₹</span>
        <span id="priceval"> {{$weights[0]->price}} </span>
        <input type="hidden" class="priceval1" value="{{$weights[0]->id}}" id="pro_ids">
    </div>

    <div class="choose-weight">
        <!-- original reads <select onchange="yes(this.value,this.data)"> -->
        <select onchange="yes(this.value,this.name)">
            @foreach($weights as $weight)
            <option id="red" name="{{$weight->id}}" data-id="{{$weight->id}}"
                    class="weight" value="{{$weight->price}}">
                {{$weight->weight}}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!--jquery function-->
<script>
function yes(pid , uid)
{
    $('#priceval').html(pid);
    alert(uid);
    //$('#pro_ids').val(uid);
}
</script>
```

Now I use `alert` to check if the value is retrieve or not (alert shows nothing then).

`this.value` is working and `this.name` is not. Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post the generated html code?

Comment: <div class="product-price">
      <div class="lefts-column"><span>₹</span>
      <span id="priceval">
        {{$weights[0]->price}}
    </span>
   <input type="hidden" class="priceval1" value="{{$weights[0]->id}}" id="pro_ids">
    </div>&nbsp&nbsp
      <div class="choose-weight">
        <select onchange="yes(this.value,this.data)">
          @foreach($weights as $weight)
        <option id="red" name="{{$weight->id}}" data-id="{{$weight->id}}" class="weight" value="{{$weight->price}}">{{$weight->weight}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: `this` refers to the select element. Which does not have a name here. The value of the selected option automatically becomes the value of the select element itself (for non-multiple selects). but it does not work that way for name. You’d need to go via the selected _index_, to access the proper option element, then you can read the name attribute directly from that.